# Error : IllegalComponentStateException when pressing JMenuItem in java swing (OSX)

Tags: java, macos, swing

During a project I stumbled upon a confusing error message that shows up when clicking any of the projects' JMenuItems. The program does continue to function but the error log gets all messy. I have also found out that the same program does NOT give any error messages when running from windows (via VM on a macbook). I tried building an extremely simplified version just showing a JMenuItem but the error message still appears.

This is the dumbed down JMenuItem test program I wrote:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
public class TestBug {
public static JMenuItem menuItem; 

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Praktikum");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocation(100,100);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu testMenu = new JMenu();
    menuItem = new JMenuItem("testMenuItem");

    testMenu.add(menuItem);
    menuBar.add(testMenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}}
```

and this is the error message showing up everytime I press the JMenuItem:

```
java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Component.java:2044)
at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen(Component.java:2018)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:390)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CAccessibility$22.call(CAccessibility.java:388)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CallableWrapper.run(LWCToolkit.java:504)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$4.dispatch(LWCToolkit.java:529)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Theres some lines about macosx in there but google has not helped me.

Thanks in forward! <3

Comment: Welcome to SO. As this seems to be your first post I'd like to say it is a very high quality one: it is clear what are you asking and you provided a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and full stack trace. You have a +1 and keep in this way!

Comment: Thank you! I will try to keep the quality up and pass it forward!

Answer (score 1):

The following variation of your program works for me on Mac OS X 10.9 with Java 8. Note that Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class TestBug {

public static JMenuItem menuItem; 

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Praktikum");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu testMenu = new JMenu("testMenu");
                menuItem = new JMenuItem("menuItem");
                testMenu.add(menuItem);
                menuBar.add(testMenu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried executing your code implementation but somehow I am still getting the same error upon pressing the JMenuItem inside the JMenu. I'm running OSX 10.10 with Java 8 and eclipse as my main IDE.

Comment: @fasoh: Ouch; this may represent a regression; verify that you have the latest [version](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601242) of Java 8 selected in Eclipse.

Comment: Unless I missed a step [I have selected the latest version](http://i.imgur.com/AP4IRT5.png) of Java 8 in eclipse. Could the reason for the problem possibly be elsewhere in my eclipse settings? I never really tinkered around with the settings so most things should be set to default, plus a reinstallation did not help so far. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure; you may need to verify that the project itself is using the latest version. Also, clean and build project, in case you're it has an old file; I sometimes build from the command line to be sure.

Comment: I have the same error with JComboBox on my MacOS. After hours of test, i see that this error comes only if you are setting that "a tap make a clic" on global trackpad setting and you make tap on your java application. If you clic it's ok (with a true mouse, it's ok too). For me is clearly a bug in Java 8 (perhaps with 7 too).

Comment: @jcstritt: Good to know; I may have to dust off my (unused) trackpad.